# Angular Display alert inside *ngIf when <td> is empty in every table row must be checked

Tags: javascript, angular

When any td is empty in any row it should display alert but my problem is if altleast one td has data and other td is empty it considers the length<0

Alert:
this is alert which will be displayed when td is empty

```
<div *ngIf="isNotExissted">
    You will be required to add VAT on every address. If you are exempt, 
</div>
```

TD:

```
<td class="col-md-2 supplier-address-types">
    <div *ngFor="let tNumber of item.taxNumber">
        {{ tNumber }}
    </div>
</td>
```

Typescript:

```
(item.taxNumber || []).forEach((checkNumber: any) => {
    if(checkNumber.taxNumber==null || typeof(checkNumber.taxNumber)=='undefined') {
        this.AllVatDataAvailable = false;
        this.taxArray1.push(this.AllVatDataAvailable);
    }
    console.log(this.taxArray1)
    if( this.taxArray1.length>0) {
        console.log("from seven four");
        this.isNotExissted = false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: a stackblitz working example would be much easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use `*ngIf` to specific list to check below way

```
 <div *ngIf="item.taxNumber.length > 0">
    You will be required to add VAT on every address. If you are exempt, 
 </div
```